# Multiplication on Fuzzy Number (a> 0, b <0)

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

If (A * B) = (a, a1, a2) LR * (b, b1, b2) LR = ((a * b, (b * a1-a * b3), (b * a3-a * b1)) LR (for a <0, b> 0 Fuzzy Number multiplication) then what is the formula for (a> 0, b <0) LR Fuzzy Number multiplication?

Check the photo below

[Fuzzy Number Multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdhRW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If `A*B` is to be the same as `B*A` then there is no need to give separate definitions for the two cases `a<0, b>0` and `a>0,b<0`. If `a<0,b>0`, just compute `B*A`. On the other hand, if fuzzy multiplication is not commutative, then you are correct that there is a gap in the book's definition.

Comment: Hello John, I would be glad if you can write the formula of  a<0, b>0 formula. Also, Did you check the attached screen shot?